# Does Python import instantiate a mystery class?

Tags: python

I thought about this for a while and can't think of a better title, sorry.

I'm new'ish to Python, and (like many other's it seems) I just can't get my head around `import`.

I think I understand 'modules' and 'packages', classes and attributes and all that.  It's one specific behavior I need clarified.

Say I have a file, foo.py.  It has one line it:

```
x = 1
```

If, in another file, I `import foo", I can reference x.  And, wonderfully, in another file I can import foo and now those two files can share x.  Leaving classes out of the discussion for simplicity, I believe this is the pythonic way to share attributes between files.

Here's the question: Is is fair to say, when I `import foo`, that foo.py itself is, (for lack of a better metaphor), secretly *instantiated* by the interpreter?

I realize if I define a class in a module, it follow traditional rules and only become instantiated if I explicitly do so.  But, the python interpreter (via the `import` statement) instantiating an instance of my module in the global namespace is the only way to explain the attribute sharing behavior.

Is this true?  Semi-true?  Or am I wandering with the Sleestaks in the Land of the Lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import creates an instance of a "module" object. It is worth knowing that this is created only the first time the module is imported. The following times it is imported you are getting a reference to the original. You can create your own module objects on the fly with a bit of instrospection.

```
import glob  # Import any python module
moduleType = type(glob)

onTheFly = moduleType("OnTheFly", "Docstring for this module")
```

Although there isn't much benefit to creating these.

Comment: YES! Good answer, and this single sentence broke my mental block - "The following times it is imported you are getting a reference to the original.".  This explains so much, and I wish this simple principle had been more evident in the official docs.

Answer (score 4):

When you import a module:

1. if the module has not been previously imported, the file is parsed in to a `module` object which is added to `sys.modules` with a key that is the import path from the pythonpath to your module
2. that module object (or some member thereof) is aliased in the importing namespace, the alias and object being referenced being determined by the specific form of `import` you used

So when you `import foo`, the interpreter checks `sys.modules` for something registered with the name `foo`.  If it finds it, it provides a label `foo` in the local namespace for the `foo` module.  If it doesn't, it searches down the pythonpath until it finds a `foo` module, parses that to a `module` object, adds that object to `sys.modules`, and adds a label in the local namespace for that module object.

`import foo as foof` does the same thing, only the local namespace label created is `foof`.  `from foo import x` follows the same process up to the point of creating a label and reference in the local namespace, instead providing a label `x` in the namespace for the attribute `x` from the `foo` module.  `from foo import x as foox` just combines the 2 ideas.

With classes, you can actually poke around this whole system by crawling up and down the tree using the `__module__` attribute.

Comment: This is a helpful and thorough explanation, but @PeterShinners answer really broke my mental block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed its true. If you execute `import foo` a module object `foo` is instatiated and the contents of your file e.g a class bar is added as a member of that object.